# parseSdk content failed error on Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

Eclipse shows `parseSdk` content failed with not even single project in it on `ubuntu 12.04 LTS`. I have also installed `JDK 6 and 7`. I am completely new to ubuntu.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the folder named ".android" and delete it.
Probably it's in your home dir. To check it try

```
ls -la ~/.android
```

To remove it:

```
rm -rf ~/.android
```

Then restart eclipse.